# Salesforce Flow - Custom Picklist Lightning Component - Default value not loaded

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, component

i built a Lightning Component to get a custom picklist in Salesforce Flow, so i can set the default value to the current selected value of a picklist and create custom validation rules. The component works fine so far but sometimes it does not load the selected value in the doInit method but just keeps the first option in the picklist "--- Bitte auswählen ---". Hope there is someone else who had this bug and found a solution to it. :)

Lightning Component - HTML

```
<aura:component controller="flow_customPicklistController" implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens,force:hasRecordId" access="global"> 
<!--When the component renders, it calls init handler.--> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/> 

<!--Declare the validation attribute so it can store the validation logic.--> 
<aura:attribute name="validate" type="Aura.Action"/> 

<!--Declaration of attributes-->
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>

<aura:attribute name="object" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="field" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="label" type="String"/>

<aura:attribute name="defaultvalue" type="String"/>

<aura:attribute name="picklistlabel" type="String[]"/>

<aura:attribute name="isBlankValue" type="boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="blankvalue" type="String" default="--- Bitte auswählen ---"/>

<aura:attribute name="errormessage" type="String" default="Bitte nehmen Sie eine Auswahl vor."/>
<aura:attribute name="outputvalue" type="String"/>

<!-- component markup --> 
<lightning:select class="picklist" aura:id="select" name="select" label="{!v.label}" onchange="{! c.onChange }" value="{!v.defaultvalue}" required="true">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isBlankValue}">
            <option value="invalid">{!v.blankvalue}</option>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
    </aura:set>
    </aura:if> 

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.picklistlabel}" var="item">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!item == v.defaultvalue}">
            <option value="{!item}" selected="true">{!item}</option>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
        </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Lightning Component - Controller

```
({ 
init: function(cmp, event, helper) {

    //alert("1");
    /* Validation of the component */
    var errormessage =  cmp.get("v.errormessage");

    cmp.set('v.validate', function() { 
        if(cmp.find('select').get('v.value') != '' && cmp.find('select').get('v.value') != 'invalid' && cmp.find('select').get('v.value') != null){ 
            cmp.set('v.outputvalue', cmp.find('select').get('v.value'));
        } 
        else{
            cmp.set('v.outputvalue', cmp.find('select').get('v.value'));
            return { 
                isValid: false, 
                errorMessage: errormessage    
            }; 
        }
    })

    /* test setting */
    //cmp.set('v.object','Projekt__c');
    //cmp.set('v.field','F_rderrunde__c');
    //cmp.set('v.label','Förderrunde');
    //cmp.set('v.defaultvalue','2018-02');

    /* Getting current value */
    helper.getCurrentValue(cmp, event, helper);

    /* IS NOW HANDLED IN UPPER METHOD Filling picklist */
    //helper.fillPicklist(cmp, event, helper);
},

onChange: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.set('v.outputvalue', cmp.find('select').get('v.value'));

    if(cmp.find('select').get('v.value') != '' && cmp.find('select').get('v.value') != 'invalid' && cmp.find('select').get('v.value') != null
        && cmp.get('v.recordId') != null && typeof cmp.get('v.recordId') != "undefined" && cmp.get('v.recordId') != ''){
        helper.updateRecord(cmp, event, helper);
    }
}})
```

Lightning Component - Helper

```
({
fillPicklist : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.getPicklistLabel");
    action.setParams({
        "objectName": cmp.get("v.object"),
        "pickListFieldName": cmp.get("v.field")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set("v.picklistlabel", response.getReturnValue());
        }else{
            alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte kontaktieren Sie die DPL.");
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

getCurrentValue : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    if(cmp.get('v.recordId') != null && typeof cmp.get('v.recordId') != "undefined" && cmp.get('v.recordId') != ''){
        var action = cmp.get("c.getCurrentValue");
        action.setParams({
            "objectName": cmp.get("v.object"),
            "pickListFieldName": cmp.get("v.field"),
            "recordId": cmp.get("v.recordId")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.defaultvalue", response.getReturnValue());
                this.fillPicklist(cmp, event, helper);
            }else{
                alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte kontaktieren Sie die DPL.");
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }else{
        this.fillPicklist(cmp, event, helper);
    }
},

updateRecord : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.updateObject");
    action.setParams({
        "objectName": cmp.get("v.object"),
        "pickListFieldName": cmp.get("v.field"),
        "recordId": cmp.get("v.recordId"),
        "updateValue": cmp.get("v.outputvalue")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        }else{
            alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte kontaktieren Sie die DPL.");
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},})
```

Lightning Component - Apex Controller

```
public without sharing class flow_customPicklistController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getPicklistLabel(String objectName, String pickListFieldName){
    List<String> picklistValues = new List<String>();
    SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = objectType.getDescribe()
                                                   .fields.getMap()
                                                   .get(pickListFieldName)
                                                   .getDescribe().getPickListValues();
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry aPickListValue : pick_list_values) {                   
        picklistValues.add(aPickListValue.getValue()); 
    }
    return picklistValues;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void updateObject(String objectName, String pickListFieldName, Id recordId, String updateValue){
    List<sObject> list_object = Database.query('SELECT Id, ' +pickListFieldName +' FROM ' +objectName +' WHERE Id = :recordId');
    SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName); 
    DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();

    for (sObject obj: list_object){

        obj.put(pickListFieldName,updateValue);

    } 

    update list_object;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String getCurrentValue(String objectName, String pickListFieldName, Id recordId){
    List<sObject> list_object = Database.query('SELECT Id, ' +pickListFieldName +' FROM ' +objectName +' WHERE Id = :recordId');
    SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName); 
    DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();

    for (sObject obj: list_object){

        obj.get(pickListFieldName);

    } 

    return (String)list_object[0].get(pickListFieldName);
}}
```